# Composition api use this

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using Vue 3 with Composition API, and I want to use a third-party package (for example [`@meforma/vue-toaster`](https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-js-toast-notification-plugin-for-vue-3/)), and it should be used like this (in Options API):

```js
import Toaster from '@meforma/vue-toaster';

createApp(App).use(Toaster).mount('#app')
```

and then in the component:

```js
this.$toast.show(`Hey! I'm here`);
this.$toast.success(`Hey! I'm here`);
this.$toast.error(`Hey! I'm here`);
this.$toast.warning(`Hey! I'm here`);
this.$toast.info(`Hey! I'm here`);
```

But `this` is not working inside the Composition API's `setup()` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`@meforma/vue-toaster` installs `$toast` on the application context](https://github.com/MeForma/vue-toaster/blob/403f8cd/src/index.js#L7-L8), which can be accessed from `getCurrentInstance().appContext.globalProperties` in `setup()`:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="showToast">Show toast</button>
</template>

<script>
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const $toast = getCurrentInstance().appContext.globalProperties.$toast
    return {
      showToast() {
        $toast.show(`Hey! I'm here`)
        $toast.success(`Hey! I'm here`)
        $toast.error(`Hey! I'm here`)
        $toast.warning(`Hey! I'm here`)
        $toast.info(`Hey! I'm here`)
        setTimeout($toast.clear, 3000)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE:** `getCurrentInstance()` is [an internal API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72209340/6277151), so it can be removed at any time. Use it with caution.

Answer (score 1):

i've the same issue.
So i've found and easy way to do:
I'm using Vite BTW.
my `main.js`

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Toaster from '@meforma/vue-toaster';

let app = createApp(App)

app.use(Toaster, {
    position: 'top-right'
}).provide('toast', app.config.globalProperties.$toast)
app.mount('#app')
```

my component:

```js
import { inject } from 'vue'
export default {
    name: 'table-line',
    
    setup(props) {
        const toast = inject('toast');
        toast.success(`it works !`)
        return {toast}
    }
}
```

Hope it could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The setup function runs one-time before the component is created. It lacks the `this` context and may not be where you would want to place these anyway. You could try putting it into a method that you can call via a button.