# Vue 3: Is getCurrentInstance() deprecated?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've seen references to `getCurrentInstance()` function on some old(?) documents and codes, but cannot find it in the current Vue 3 document.

Is `getCurrentInstance()` deprecated?

If so, what is the reason? (`inject()` considered enough?) If not, why can't I find it in the document?

Comment: Doc:
https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance .

Source code of `getCurrentInstance()`: 
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/main/src/v3/currentInstance.ts

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`getCurrentInstance()` was removed from the Vue 3 docs because it's an [internal API](https://github.com/vuejs/docs/issues/1422#issuecomment-1032120675):

> Because the instance is an internal instance that exposes non-public APIs. Anything you use from that instance can technically break between any release types, since they are not subject to semver constraints.

---

`getCurrentInstance()` was originally [documented in 4-Oct-2020](https://github.com/vuejs/docs/pull/590), but that was later [removed in 31-Aug-2021](https://github.com/vuejs/docs/commit/1ea66dc0e67abe5c518d487218bb7e2d6a5c5324) in a major refactoring of the Composition API docs by the creator of Vue (Evan You). Despite its removal from the docs, `getCurrentInstance()` still:

- [is widely used in Vue core](https://github.com/vuejs/core/search?q=getCurrentInstance).
- [is not documented as deprecated in code](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/d52907f/packages/runtime-core/src/component.ts#L561).
- [is exported as part of the Advanced API](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/9c304bfe7942a20264235865b4bb5f6e53fdee0d/packages/runtime-core/src/index.ts#L78-L82).

Given that it's an undocumented internal API, use it with caution.

Comment: so how can I get $el?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12596#issuecomment-1173269807

quoting the comment from evan,

> getCurrentInstance is used mostly for official vue libraries that need additional internal access, not for userland application code. It was mistakenly documented in WIP v3 docs but is no longer considered a public API

Answer (score 1):

The `VueUse` library extensively uses `getComponentState()` to detect if code is called within the component lifecycle.

For example:

https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/shared/tryOnBeforeUnmount/index.ts

I'm going to go out on a limb and say,

> *"If it is good enough for the VueUse maestro `antfu`, it is good enough for me."*

So although officially `deprecated`, it is still **essential** until Vue provides a method such as `isInComponentLifecycle()`.

My recommendation is to only use it for this type of detection, and avoid accessing it's members if possible.