# Importing result from <script> into <script setup>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I’m trying to enumerate the instances of a Vue component in order to ensure unique ids, and for that use a simple generator. Normally I would initiate the generator outside of the `setup` function:

```js
const idGen = generateIds("component:my-component");

export default {
  setup() {
    const id = idGen.next().value;

    return {
      id,  // e.g. "component:my-component/0042"
    };
  },
};
```

However with the `<script setup>` sugar I’m not exactly sure how this is done. I know I can run side-effect in another `<script>` block which will only be executed once:

```
<script>
const idGen = generateIds("component:my-component");
</script>
```

However I don’t know I to access the shared `idGen` in my `<script setup>` to increment the enumerator and get the unique id.

```
<script setup>
// Where do I get idGen from the above <script>?
const id = idGen.next().value;
</script>
```

The only way I can think of to do this while using the `<script setup>` sugar is to initiate the generator in a separate file:

```
<script setup>
import { idGen } from "./id-generator.js";

const id = idGen.next().value;
</script>
```

The only problem is that it is a bit annoying to create a separate file just for this tiny logic which very much belongs with the component, so I would avoid it if I could.

Comment: if `<script>` is above `<script setup>` then `idGen` *should* be available in `<script setup>`

Comment: Huh, I never thought it would be that simple... Thanks.

Comment: Added an answer - I think this may trip up others that start using `<script setup>`

Comment: Could possibly be solved in more idiomatic way by making generateIds a composable that keeps global state in a weak map.

Comment: This is the reason I consider script setup syntax faulty by design. It's DSL and not proper JS. And it's supposed to make things simpler in 90% cases, but you don't know beforehand when 10% will make them complex, and refactoring back to script may be tedious.

Comment: @EstusFlask So something like a `useIdGenerator('unique-component-name')`?

Comment: @RúnarBerg Yes. And in case you need just unique comp ids not determined by readable strings, it could be simplified to `getCurrentInstance().uid`

Comment: @EstusFlask It looks like `getCurrentInstance` is [currently undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209080/vue-3-is-getcurrentinstance-deprecated) I don’t think I trust my self to use it in production code. Alternatively I could just pull a third party UUID generator.

Comment: @RúnarBerg It can be pretty much trusted, it's undocumented but widely used by third-party plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: turns out the order is irrelevant after all

any `<script>` will run as normal

the code inside `<script setup>` is converted/compiled to a *composition API* "setup" function, and when that is called, all the top-level code in other `<script>` will have already executed, therefore `idGen` will already be available

so

Ignore the rest of this answer

---

<s>Most vue3 `<script setup>` examples that use another `<script>` always show the order</s>

```
<script setup></script>
<script></script>
```

In your case, this won't work.

However, if the scripts are in this order

```
<script>
const idGen = generateIds("component:my-component");
</script>
```

then

```
<script setup>
const id = idGen.next().value;
</script>
```

then `idGen` will be available inside the `<script setup>`

Note: you can have as many `<script>` tags in your SFC as you want, in any order, but only one `<script setup>`

Comment: Not really. Vue SFC is a made-up syntax, so is `script setup`. It may work the way you describe, but it's not because things work like that in a browser

Comment: OK - well, this answer is actually wrong ... I assumed the OP had an issue with defining `idGen` in `<script>` perhaps because script was after script setup ... turns out, the order is irrelevant ... it works, because `idGen` is global, and the code in `script setup` runs when the component is *created* which will always be after non setup `<script>` is executed - please unaccept the answer so I can delete this misinformation